# WAMP is not getting started

Tags: windows-xp, windows-service

I am not the admin of my computer.
I have installed WAMP 2.0 successfully on Windows XP, but I am not able to start it. When I try, it doest not give any error, just it does not start.

Answer (score 1):

According to: http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,63061

You must be an admin to run the server.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can ask your IT team to create a local admin user account for you, which you can use to run Wamp. Use 'Run As' and key in the local admin user credentials to run wamp. That's what we do where I code.

Of course, this may not be possible in your workplace, in which case you can set up a LAMP stack using Centos or whatever Linux distro you like, and use the apache-mysql-php goodness it offers. I think setting up a LAMP stack VM slice within Virtual Box could also be possible, not entirely sure about the network communication setup for this though.